# Copy app.config for deployment

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

If I have projects that are deployed by copying files (executables, dll's and data files) to their destination folder, is it correct that I can ommit copying the app.config-file (`executableName.config`) because it will created anyway on the first app startup per user in the users local storage?

Or otherwise asked, is it right, that the app.config (`executableName.config`) in the exeutables directory `/bin/debug` or `/bin/release` is only for debuging purposes there and could be deleted without any implications?

I have tested and used this without problems so far (deleting and not deploying the config file) but maybe there exist some side effects that are not obvious at the first glance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx) article is the [AppName].exe.config file will be merged with the other configuration files (eg Machine.config, User.config) when configuration is requested by the code.

Thus, if you don't have any configuration and choose to omit the exe config you shouldn't have any issues.

The exe config is **not** used for debugging purposes.

Comment: +1 wal: Thanks for the link, it made a lot of things clear (have not read all :). Yes, [AppName].exe.config is definitively not for debuging purposes. I have seen this now.

Comment: Yes, a lot to read at that link, who would have thought there is so much to the humble config file!

Answer (score 1):

The pdb files are for debugging and not the config file. Config files are for configuration. Since you are already creating it per user on startup, hence you can delete it.

There is no side effect of keeping the app.config file in some other location. Sometimes this is desirable. For instance you need to share app.config file between your projects then you can keep this file in the solution folder and use it in all three projects.

Comment: I'm not creating it at app startup. This is the job of the runtime (but not for the app root, I assume). The question is, if it must exist in the app root.

Comment: @HCL. Basically this file (executablename.config) is created based on the app.config file. Hence all the information defined in app.config is defined in it too. The runtime environment uses configuration information from this file (executablename.config). There would be no side effect if

Comment: @HCL. If you have an app.config file added to application root then this file (executablename.config) will be created in the debug or release folder, based on the information specified in the app.config. If app.config is not present in your app root then this file (executablename.config) is not created.

Comment: @HCL. Even if you keep the app.config file in some folder and not on the root. Executablename.config would be created in the debug/release folder.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer and the comments. I was aware how the settings files were created. What I didn't know was, why application settings were available, even though I deleted the executables config file. The answer from wal showed helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen `.config` files generate themselves before. The most common approach is to use the `application deployment framework` which takes the .config file used for development and modifies it based on the environment you're deploying to. Eg in our project we have:

```
web.config
web.development.config
web.testing.config
web.production.config
```

web.config has everything in it, the others contain transforms eg...

web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="<Dev connection string>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and in web.production.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString"
      connectionString="<Production connection string>"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

So when I publish to production using the publish tool, it modifies my config file on-the-fly.

For more information, google `AppDeploy`

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However my question is about executable projects, not asp.net. Sorry, maybe I should have mentioned this more clearly.

Comment: @HCL Probably careless reading on my part. Hope you get an answer